# Finding the ratio of students who attended less than $H/2$ hours of lectures

Tags: calculus

MATH125 students must attend $t$ hours, where $t ∈ [0, H]$, of lectures and pass four obligatory exercises to qualify for the end of semester examination. The number of students who attended between $t_1$ and $t_2$ hours of lectures is described by the integral

$$\int^{t_2}_{t_1} 20t^2dt ,\qquad 0≤ t_1 < t_2 ≤ H$$

Some students attended less than $H/2$
hours of lectures and passed the obligatory
exercises so they are qualified to take the examination.

Find the ratio of students who attended less than $H/2$ hours of lectures

Comment: I have edited your integral - is that what you wanted?

Comment: You might find the values when $t_1=0$ and $t_2=H/2$ and when $t_1=0$ and $t_2=H$, and then consider what those values represent

Comment: @Henry Yeah, thanks man :)